# Making Observable-Array Observable

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to show a different picture when it either is a favorite or not
I'm getting the data from a data-base with breeze.js

```
<span class="projektZeile" data-bind="visible: isFavorite">
 <a href="" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.makeNoFavorite(projectName,data, event)}" ><img src="../../Content/Images/isFavorite.png"/></a>                           
</span>


  <span class="projektZeile" data-bind="visible: !isFavorite">     
        <a href="" data-bind="click: function(data, event) {$parent.makeFavorite(projectName,data, event)}" ><img src="../../Content/Images/makeFavorite.png"/></a>
      </span>
```

Here is the code where i fill the observable Array

```
self.favoriten.push({ projectName: item.Values[0].Name,
                            isFavorite: ko.observable(item.Values[0].IsFavorite())
                        });
```

Now my problem is, that if it is a favorite the right button is shown, but when it's not a favorite no picture is shown..

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the image is being served to the page correctly? Use Fiddler (or the network tab of developer tools) and check that the image is available to the browser, as the code looks fine to me.

Failing that, you can always use isFavorite() in your enable test to actually test the value, though I did think that Knockout should be able to cope with what you've put.

Comment: The problem was the isFavourite()! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect a problem with your image path for non-favorites. To figure out what's going on use the developer tools of your favorite browser and observe the DOM.